# Duplicate a nested Map to a MutableMap in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Given a nested immutable map of:

```
val someNestedMap = mapOf(
    2 to mapOf(
        "a" to true,
        "b" to false,
        "c" to true
    ),
    3 to mapOf(
        "d" to false,
        "e" to true,
        "f" to false
    )
)
```

If I want a new copy of this exact structure, but with each of the maps to be mutable, is there an easy way to do this in Kotlin?

I want to create a copy of the above as `val newCopy: MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, Boolean>>`

Answer (score 2):

You can one-line this by mapping the keys and then converting the whole map:

```
return immutableMap.mapValues { it.value.toMutableMap() }.toMutableMap()
```

You could make a generic extension function out of it like this:

```
fun <K, VK, VV> Map<K, Map<VK, VV>>.toDeeplyMutableMap() = 
    mapValues { it.value.toMutableMap() }.toMutableMap()
```

I think this is too specific of a use case for a standard library function. Nested mutable collections are kind of error prone.

Comment: Thank you Tenfour04, and thanks for the heads up on nested mutable collections, I'll have another look and see if I can avoid them in that case!

Answer (score 0):

Once again, I came up with something soon after posting. Not sure if it's the best approach though, feels like there should be a native function for this:

```
fun copyIt(immutableMap: Map<Int, Map<Int, Boolean>>): MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, Boolean>>
{
    val newCopy: MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, Boolean>> = mutableMapOf()

    for (mapValue in immutableMap.entries) {
        newCopy[mapValue.key] = mapValue.value.toMutableMap()
    }

    return newCopy
}
```